# Android: JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, arrays, json

This is the sample `JSON array` from the server.

```
[  
   {  
      "users":{  
         "uid":"5893048cc3a841.21437792",
         "name":"Jakob Nolan",
         "email":"jakob.nolan@gmail.com"
      }
   },
   {  
      "users":{  
         "uid":"589308eb640e79.86708812",
         "name":"Donald Trump",
         "email":"donaldtrump@usa.com"
      }
   }
]
```

I'm trying to use `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` to get the values inside. So I wrote a code as follows.

```
   String strResponse = response.body().string();
    Log.i("Superman", strResponse);
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strResponse);
        boolean error = jsonObject.getBoolean("error");
        Log.i(TAG, ""+error);

        if(!error) {
            JSONArray people = jsonObject.getJSONArray("users");
            JSONObject obj = people.getJSONObject(0);
            final String name = obj.getString("name");
            Log.i("TAG", name);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "it works! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            final String strError = jsonObject.getString("error_msg");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            hideDialog();
        }
    } catch (final JSONException e) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG, "JSONException caught: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

I ran the code above, and I got the `JSONException` as follows.

```
02-03 17:22:14.091 27684-27684/com.marshall.authentication I/MainActivity: JSONException caught: Value [{"users":{"uid":"5893048cc3a841.21437792","name":"Jakob Nolan","email":"jakob.nolan@gmail.com"}},{"users":{"uid":"589308eb640e79.86708812","name":"Donald Trump","email":"donaldtrump@usa.com"}}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Did I do something wrong while parsing the JSON objects out of the JSON array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you are receiving is not valid. At least not for the given situation. You now have an **unnamed** array with **named** objects. To have a proper array with users, it should look like this:

```
{
    "users": [
       {    
           "uid":"5893048cc3a841.21437792",
           "name":"Jakob Nolan",
           "email":"jakob.nolan@gmail.com"
       },
       {  
          "uid":"589308eb640e79.86708812",
          "name":"Donald Trump",
          "email":"donaldtrump@usa.com"
       }
    ]
}
```

Also the response you are getting now is an `JSONArray`, since it's wrapped with `[ ]`. So in that case you should use a `JSONArray` instead of a `JSONObject`. I like to wrap JSON in `{ }` So I always can parse it as an object, and from there obtain any array, as in this case `"urers"`.

Comment: Any suggestions for the solution?

Comment: If you are unable to change the JSON, then I think you might be able to achieve what you want with d1vivek681065's answer. But the JSON your are receiving, although syntax wise valid, doesn't look like a normal Array of users.

Comment: @MarshallS.Lee see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your response is `JSONArray` but you are parsing it as `JSONObject`. Do as below:

```
    JSONArray responseArray = new JSONArray(strResponse);
    for(int i =0; i<responseArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject eachObject = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);
        //do other parsing in each object
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strResponse);
```

Your response is not json object, it is json array. Every item in that array is an object called `users`

Answer (score 0):

look above in your `logcat`, your response is returning `JSONArray`. 
And what your actually trying to do is to convert that `JSONArray` to `JSONObject`

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strResponse);
```

This is classFile code.

try changing this to

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(strResponse);
```

and further to get JSONObject's from above you can parse this JSONArray
Like

```
for(int i =0; i<jsonArray .length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsonObject= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray people = jsonObject.getJSONArray("users");
    String name = people.getString("name");
    //do other parsing in each string
}
```

and remove

```
boolean error = jsonObject.getBoolean("error");
```

if there is no `boolean` type value in your JSON.